# Displaying an array of alphabetically sorted AR objects inside the letters of the alphabet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array of AR objects that I've been able to sort alphabetically that I need to split by letter, for example { :a => [apple], :b => [banana] } and so on, based on an attribute that I use for sorting.
The end result should be something like

```
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <ul>
    <li> Apple </li>
  </ul>
  <li>B</li>
  <ul>
    <li> Banana </li>
```

and so on.
I have no idea how to do this...
The array is already sorted alphabetically using the DB.

Can someone help me?
  ngw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
objects.group_by { |obj| obj.name[0].to_sym }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this into a helper:

```
def my_objects_in_groups_by_first_letters(objects, name_method, &block)
  first_letters = objects.map {|o| o.send(name_method)[0, 1].upcase}.uniq
  first_letters.each do |c|
    yield c, objects.select {|o| o.send(name_method)[0, 1].upcase == c}
  end
end
```

and use this method in view:

```
<ul>
  <% my_objects_in_groups_by_first_letters(@objects, :name) do |letter, objects| -%>
    <li>
      <%= letter %>
      <ul>
        <% objects.each do |o| -%>
          <li><%= o.name %></li>
        <% end -%>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <% end -%>
</ul>
```